# React js cannot return data from function

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have two functions, one is a page that calls for data from a function that gets data to and from a server.

The function that gets data to and from a server:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState, createRef, lazy, useContext } from "react";
import { UserContext } from "./UserContext";

import jwt_decode from "jwt-decode";

import axios from "axios";

export async function getProtectedAsset(url, user, setUser) {
  try {
    const res = await axios
      .post(url, token)
      .then((res) => {
        console.log(res.data);
        return res.data;
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.error(err);
      });
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
    throw err;
  }
}
```

The code that calls this function:

```
useEffect(async () => {
    try {
      let res = await getProtectedAsset(
        "http://127.0.0.1:5002/mypage",
        user,
        setUser
      );

      console.log(res);
      
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error.message);
    }
  }, []);
```

`getProtectedAsset` will do a successful `console.log(res.data);` with the data from the server. The calling function that uses useEffect when doing `console.log(res);` will write `undefined` to the console.

Why can't I simply return from the function? Obviously the data is received from the server, but for some reason a function cannot return it? I am very confused

Thank you for your help!

Comment: you're not returning `res` from your `getProtectedAsset` function

Comment: "return res.data;" ???

Comment: Yes you have to had a return at the end of your function `getProtectedAsset` -> `return res`

Comment: You are mixing `async` and `.then`. If you are awaiting async function, skip the `then` and `catch` and just return `res` in the same scope as you declare it. You are already `catch`ing using a `try/catch` block

Comment: first change res in to json  before return

Comment: @Nsevens is correct. You are returning in the `then` callback. However, `getProtectedAsset` is just declaring a value and doing nothing with it. Implicitly, you are returning undefined

Comment: @AbrahamLabkovsky even if I return in the end of getProtectedAsset I still get the same error

Comment: Have a read of this: https://devtrium.com/posts/async-functions-useeffect

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not use `async` in `useEffect`. This is not supported.

I am not sure why you can't use `getProtectedAsse(...).then(res=> {})`.

But if you want to run getProtectedAsse() synchronously, try like the following instead.

```
useEffect(() => {
    const asyncInternalFunc = async () => {
      try {
        let res = await getProtectedAsset(
          "http://127.0.0.1:5002/mypage",
          user,
          setUser
        );
        console.log(res);
        return res;
      } catch (error) {
        console.error(error.message);
      }
    }
    asyncInternalFunc().then();
  }, []);
```

Updated async function to return the response.

```
export async function getProtectedAsset(url, user, setUser) {
  try {
    const res = await axios.post(url, token);
    return res;
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
    throw err;
  }
}
```

Comment: This console.log(res); still returns undefined :/

Comment: Please check my updated post out.

Comment: I wouldn't even define a constant for rez . just `return await axios.post(url, token);` - But by this point the entire function is becoming redundant and the `user`, `setUser` params don't even get used.

Comment: That updated post solved my issue! Thank you! I am very grateful for you and all other people here on stack overflow that is so helpful and nice! :)

Comment: @Pellay doing return immediately also worked. There are some code before the server call that uses the user and setUser states that I removed for this post just to keep it clean :)

Comment: I'd recommend you do read through the article I linked in the comments above, it explains why and how this works.